# isJoi = true; SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Tags: typescript, npm, nestjs, joi

I'm working on a NestJs backend on multiple machines. One machine is not able to deal with the [@hapi/joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi) package. When running the NestJs application  in development mode I get this error

PS C:\Users\mhermsen\Desktop\joi-test> npm run start:dev

```
> joi-test@0.0.1 start:dev C:\Users\mhermsen\Desktop\joi-test
> nest start --watch

8:32:49 AM - Starting compilation in watch mode...


8:32:51 AM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
C:\Users\mhermsen\Desktop\joi-test\node_modules\@hapi\joi\lib\errors.js:246
    isJoi = true;
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mhermsen\Desktop\joi-test\node_modules\@hapi\joi\lib\index.js:9:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

I tried to reproduce the problem. First, I created a new Nest application via `nest new joi-test`. Next I installed joi via

```
$ npm install --save @hapi/joi
$ npm install --save-dev @types/hapi__joi
```

I removed most of the code. The **src** directory only contains a **main.ts** file with

```
import * as Joi from "@hapi/joi";

Joi.object({
  num: Joi.number()
}).validate({
  port: "abc"
});
```

There is no Nest related code anymore so I think this has nothing to do with Nest. When removing the validation and only import the package, the code works fine.

```
import * as Joi from "@hapi/joi";

console.log("This is fine now");
```

Other machines work fine, this only appears on this machine. Any ideas how to fix it?

---

**Update:**
I tested it on another company machine and this machine fails too. So my private Linux machines seem to work and my company Windows 10 machines seem to throw this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I think you use joi v17 with node < v12

[Joi](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/) 17 works with node >= 12. So you have to use node 12 or downgrade to Joi-v.17

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nvm, in your terminal, upgrade your node version like this

```
$ nvm install 12
$ nvm use 12
```

and restart your node app.

This is a nice tutorial on how to install nvm
https://dev.to/jlouiss/how-to-use-nvm-and-why-4e05